# tensorflow quantization error

Tags: tensorflow, quantization

when my graph is as follows, it will fail to quantize, the error info is **AssertionError: Failed to quantized constant ones_1 of type**

```
x = tf.ones((1000,1),'int32')
*ones = tf.ones((1, 100), "int32")*
x = tf.reshape(x, shape=(-1,1))
```

when I change graph to the following, it works:

```
x = tf.ones((1000,1),'int32')
***ones = tf.ones((1, 100), "int32")
ones = tf.reshape(ones, shape=(1,-1))***
x = tf.reshape(x, shape=(-1,1))
```

Comment: What command are you using to quantize?